# Skip else condition in case statement erlang

Tags: erlang

I have a list of list (`AllData`) over which I'm iterating, to get some elements depending on sepc-documentation  conditions. Keeping empty tuple `{}` or only `ok` is causing issues to my list and really I don't want to insert anything to my NewList in else(`_->`) block of inner case statement.

Can we skip the else ( _-> ) condition?

Here is my sample code:

```
lists:foldl(fun(X , {Counter, NewList}) ->
        case X:number() of 
          {Aa, Bb} ->
            case  X:id() == Aa of 
                true ->
                    //Aa matched 
                     {Counter+1, [X:items()|NewList] }  
                _->
                    %% I want to skip the code that goes here in inner case statement.
                    %% Doing anything here showing a wrong output. 
                    %% Keeping empty tuple with counter changing my output like 
                         {Counter+1, [[]|NewList] }  
                    %% I don't have to do anything here at all.

                end;
            _->
                 %% Execute some other code and append to J
                 {Counter+1, [X:items()|NewList] }  
         end
    end,{0, []}, AllData).
```

Comment: Given your questions, I'd strongly advise reading a good Erlang tutorial (like http://learnyousomeerlang.com/content up to "A Short Visit to Common Data Structures") before continuing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just return `Counter` and `NewList` unchanged:

```
{Counter, NewList }
```

Comment: But I don't want to change my counter sequence. now I'm getting [{1, []}, {2, []}, {3, []}, {5, []}, {6, []}, {10, []}].

Comment: Was that this much simple! I'm newbie to erlang.

Comment: It was this simple. :-) With `lists:foldl` you just pass the accumulator straight through unchanged if you don't want to change it.